# unable to load data into big query table by BigQueryOperator in composer

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I have created the dag to load the data from big query to another big query table. I have used the BigQueryOperator in composer . But this code is not working as expected. I'm not able to get the error can any one please help me resolve this issue.

And i manually created empty table also still data in not loading into the table.Please find the below code and let me know did i missed any thing?

```
from typing import Any
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import airflow
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

sql="""SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset_name.source_table`"""

DEFAULT_ARGUMENTS = {
    "owner": "Airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2019, 8, 7),
    "schedule_interval": '0 6 * * *',
    "retries": 10
}

dag = models.DAG(
        dag_id='Bq_to_bq',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGUMENTS
    )
LOAD_TABLE_TRUNC = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id ='load_bq_table_truncate',
    dag=dag,
    bql=sql,
    destination_proect_dataset_table='project-id.dataset-name.table_name',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    allow_large_results='true',
    use_legacy_sql=False,

)

LOAD_TABLE_APPEND = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id ='load_bq_table_append',
    dag=dag,
    bql=sql,
    destination_proect_dataset_table='project-id.dataset-name.table_name',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    allow_large_results='true',
    use_legacy_sql=False,

)
LOAD_TABLE_TRUNC.set_downstream(LOAD_TABLE_APPEND)
```

Comment: `BigQueryOperator` expects a boolean primitive value for `allow_large_results`. You have `'true'` when this should be `True` without the quotes. I doubt this is the reason for the problem, however. Checking the logs like suggested would be the best approach

Answer (score 1):

**This is to find out error specific to the DAG's failure**

You can find out error in two ways

- Web Interface:

  1. Go to the DAG and select Graph view.
  2. Select the task and click on View Log.
- Stack Driver logging:

  1. Go to this URL https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer? project=project_id.
  2. Select 'Cloud Composer Environment' from first dropdown followed by location and DAG name.
  3. Select Error as from Log level dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

As Josh mentioned in his comment on your post, the value for `allow_large_results` should be `True` without the quotes. Additionally, I see that you have a typo in your spelling of `destination_proect_dataset_table`. You're missing a 'j': `destination_project_dataset_table`

BVSKanth's recommendations for finding DAG errors are also spot-on and worth considering for future debugging.